# Computer freezes for 30 seconds when print is clicked

Tags: windows-xp, printer, network-printer

I've just installed new printer drivers on 5 existing computers.

For some reason, 4 of those 5 computers have not had a problem, you click print and it prints.  However, the 1 remaining computer seems to freeze for about 30 seconds when the print button is clicked before it prints.

What kind of additional information will I have to provide here to get help trouble shoot why the computer is freezing for 30 seconds?

And how do I go about trouble shooting this issue?

All computers have:

- OS: Windows XP Pro
- Printer: KONICA MINOLTA C452
- Connection: Network printer

Comment: Any helpful messages in your Event Viewer?

Comment: I'll check now.

Comment: Nope, no new events are recorded in the event viewer when I click the print button.

Comment: If you run task manager, does anything increase in memory or CPU?

Comment: Are the other 4 computers not Windows XP machines? Are they connected differently to the printer?

Comment: @admintech, I will try that out tomorrow.

Comment: @The White Phoenix, All the computers are exactly the same, i.e. GX720's and all of them have Windows XP Pro installed.  They are all connected to the printer the same way and all of them have the same driver and printer settings.

Comment: Is the driver the latest available version? As silly as it sounds, I imagine if you contacted Konika support it probably wont have been the first time they've heard of this issue. I would also say it might be an idea to use Performance Monitor to further diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Ruairi Fullam, where do I get Performance Monitor from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any other printers attached locally or via network to this problem-child computer? If so, are they all online? Or do you have any mapped network drives that are no longer available? This is usually the cause of 'lags' like you're experiencing.